# Is the wall in this blue print able to be removed? (Blueprint in Spanish.)

Tags: walls, structural, construction, removal

[image][image]

I am looking at a home to purchase in Queretaro, MX where I have been transferred for five years. There is a two year old home in a great location for the right price but the rooms are really small. We have no children so losing a bedroom wouldn't be bad. I was hoping to make a larger master bedroom by taking out the wall between the current Master and bedroom 1 the second floor. I put yellow dots on the wall to come out. I don't have time to contact a Mexico architect as this house should sell fast and I'm currently in the US. I would feel so much better knowing before I made an offer and paid earnest money.

The only things needed to be moved in the wall are a TV cable line. There is an electrical outlet in the wall for both rooms. This home is made of typical Mexico materials like steel frames and concrete. There is no wood joists or drywall. If I can't do this, my wife insists on taking our second choice of a house which means a commute for me. Any ideas?

Thank you!

Comment: Is this a duplex or part of a string of houses? Chances are very high that it's a bearing wall, but only a competent individual on site can tell you for sure. On the plus side, people knock out bearing walls and replace them with beams all the time.

Comment: Yes, it is a string of homes. This one is on the end.